# How can I fork many child process in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, fork

I would like to produce child processes and download simultaneously (I know not actually `simultaneous`, but looks like it happens `simultaneous`) with `wget` in each process.

```
for download_cmd in cmd_list:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        fd = subprocess.Popen(download_cmd)
    else:
        cur_num_of_process += 1

if pid != 0:
    while cur_num_of_process > 0 :
        os.wait()
        cur_num_of_process -= 1
```

but it doesn't work. Any help, please?

Python version is 3.x

Comment: Your forks are continuing to run the `for download_cmd in cmd_list:` loop. But there's no point in forking in the first place if all your forks ever do is spawn processes, as those run asynchronously anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting for each child, and so you never create more than one.

---

Classic fork bomb, in python. Try this only as an experiment, only on your own equipment (not on a computer lab's systems, for example), and be ready to handle the consequences.  This demonstrates forking many (many, many) child processes.

```
while True:
    os.fork()
```

---

What you want is to create a collection of processes, then wait on them after each has been started.

```
workers = []
for cmd in [...]:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
    workers.append(proc)

for proc in workers:
    proc.wait()
```